# Is it possible find users from trusted domain by using UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity

Tags: c#, active-directory, account-management

We have two domains with one-way trust.

Domain EXT that has External one-way trust configured to domain INT. So I would like to connect to EXT domain by using EXT domain user credentials and search for users that are in INT domain.

**The question** - Is it possible by using default API like?:

```
var found = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 
    IdentityType.SamAccountName, 'a.someone');
```

Where 'a.someone' is SamAccountName for user from INT domain.

Where 'context' initialized like the following:

```
var contextOptions = ContextOptions.Negotiate | 
ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing;

var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "EXT.loc", 
null, contextOptions, "EXT\\Administrator", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [thread about AD search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628977/limiting-the-attributes-returned-in-an-ldap-query). 
PrincipalContext is not bad, easy-to-use in few situation, but not complete enough.

Concerning authentication, it depends of the execution environment. 
Someone asked for [this point here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930580/how-to-modify-ad-object-on-parent-domain-controller-from-child-dc/11931237#11931237).

I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I tried examples from links above but with no luck yet. Looks like it wont work in the way I want.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your updated code and the complete processes you made since your first post ?