# How to modify AD object on Parent Domain Controller from child DC?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have 1 domain in which there is 1 parent DC and other is child DC, parent DC has 1 Active directory object for example- OU. I want to change properties of this OU object by using an application running on child DC. This application is written in C#. I am using `DirectoryEntry` class for this purpose. I am able to read properties of OU object, but when I try to Modify its value,i am getting exception as "Access Denied". I can set same property when i run app on parent DC.
Do I need to give some extra permission ? If yes, then how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of application is it about ?

I had this kind of issue with a website designed for active directory management.
The execution environment was not allowed to manage AD so far.
So, through IIS, we changed the default account to local system.

If it's a WinForm app, your local administrator should be a forest admin or an administrator member of the concerned AD.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, it is working.Can we give this permission through programming.I mean does Directory entry class have such property or method to give this permission

Comment: I don't think so. I looked for this a lot and this was the only way to solve this issue. But you can provide specific permissions to OU or other entry objects, the same way you do with folders and files.